# Best way to get integer end of a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

Given an identifier foo consisting of letters, numbers, and underscores, I want to split the string on the last integer.  Examples:

```
"hello" => "hello", ""
"hello0" => "hello", "0"
"hello001" => "hello", "001"
"h123ello123" => "h123ello", "123"
```

I imagine I could use a regular expression to pull out this information, but wasn't sure that was the cleanest approach (and if it is, what that expression would look like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this split

```
split("(?=\\d*$)",2);
```

It will split on place [before](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) [zero or more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) digits (`\\d`) which have end of string `$` after it (which means they are at the end of string).
Parameter `2` will limit size of result array to two elements preventing this regex from farther splitting in places I marked `|` below

```
hello0|0|1
```

so result will be `hello` `001`.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/poxH0F)**

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex for your `Pattern.matcher(string)` method call:

```
^(.+?)(\d*)$
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^(.+?)(\\d*)$" );
```

And then use `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` for your matches (after calling `matcher.find()`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the regular string "hello"

Comment: It gives `"hello"` and `""` when input is `"hello"`. What did you expect?

Comment: I take back what I said I was invoking it incorrectly.  This does work, and I upvoted.  I went with the other answer because I found it simpler and easier to implement.